# how to locate element by XPATH in Selenium

Tags: html, selenium, flask

How to get element "faceCanvasPhoto" by XPATH using selenium

I tried this its not working

```
WebDriverWait(driver, 5).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.ID, "faceCanvasPhoto"))
```

HTML

```
<body>
<div class = "container-fluid body-content">
  ::before
<div class ="col-xs-8 col-pr-8">...</div>
<div class ="col-xs-4 col-pr-4" col-rhs>
    <canvas id = "faceCanvasBack" class="center">
         </canvas>
    <br>
    <canvas id="faceCanvasPhoto" class = "center-block">
         </canvas>
```

Answer (score 0):

One of the reasons  could be that your canvas tags might be inside iframes.if so try to switch frame and then search.
Another way to you can try to get an element would be

```
driver.findElements(By.tagName("canvas")).get(1)
```

Or

```
driver.findElements(By.Xpath("//canvas[@id='faceCanvasPhoto']  ))
```

Ps-Ignore formatting using mobile  device